# Creating different shape buttons?

Tags: qt4

I have to implement different shapes button like round shape , ellipse shape. How do i start Please give a direction , example code.

I am new to qt and in my first application i have to implement the same.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own subclass of button deriving from [QAbstractButton](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html).  Then you can draw it in any shape you want.

Comment: I am subclassing the QAbstractButton class but i am not successful in creating hexagon shape. Please guide me. How to implement a hexagon shape , i have created round , ovel shape but not succeed in hexagon shape.

Comment: I have subclassing the buttonClass and using paintEvent method but i am not succeed in getting hexagon shape. I am using drawpolygon method to create hexagon. Please anyone help me.I am confused .

Answer (score 0):

you can use [qt stylesheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html).

For example;

```
QPushButton{
border-radius: 40;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This approch of customiz i have used.i have to create this type of button.